# Cannot call value of non-function type 'HTTPURLResponse?' Alamofire 4, Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, alamofire

I want to use Alamofire to send an email with Mailgun. I'm using the below code to send the request, but I'm getting error `Cannot call value of non-function type 'HTTPURLResponse?'` on line starting with `.response`.

How can I fix this? I'm trying to replicate the code found here but update it for Swift 3. I'm trying to send an email using Mailgun and Alamofire.

https://gist.github.com/makzan/11e8605f85352abf8dc1/

Thanks!

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters)
                                .authenticate(user: "api", password: key)
                                .response{ (request, response, data, error) in
                                    println(request)
                                    println(response)
                                    println(error)
                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth taking a look at the [Alamofire migration pages](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#making-requests) for these sorts of issues.

You'll see there that responses are now handled like so:

```
// Alamofire 3
Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString).response { request, response, data, error in
    print(request)
    print(response)
    print(data)
    print(error)
}

// Alamofire 4
Alamofire.request(urlString).response { response in // method defaults to `.get`
    debugPrint(response)
}
```